# Can a positive-control thyratron be used as a logic inverter/NOT gate?

Tags: digital-logic, vacuum-tube

FTR: I am not actually planning on building a vacuum tube computer. But I am interested as to whether one could build an inverter circuit using a thyratron and string an odd number of them together to form a ring oscillator.

Comment: Probably not : it remains conducting when the input is removed (until the anode supply is also removed) like a thyristor, forming a kind of latch. In a specialised scenario where the anode supply is pulsed, then maybe. What's wrong with a simple triode?

Comment: It is possible, I haven't used cold cathode thyratrons.

Answer (score 1):

**No**. The way thyratrons work is that once the ionization arc is initiated, the grid loses control over the current flow. It isn't until the cathode-anode voltage difference drops below the ionization potential that the tube cuts off.